# Finding the difference between rows of columns using shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I've been coming here for almost two years now and have always been able to figure things out but I'm stumped now. Hopefully this is a quick answer.

https://github.com/MPhillips55/Capstone-Project-2---League-of-Legends/blob/master/EDA/test_case.csv

The link there is what my data looks like. 'min_0', 'min_1' and so on are gold values for League of Legends games at 1 minute intervals, that continue on to 'min_80'. The csv should be available to download.

I want to subtract the red values from the blue values and store that number on the blue rows for each minute.

Then I want to subtract the blue values from the red values and store that number on the red rows for each minute.

For clarity, I am only interested in the comparison for matching 'match_id's.

Here is an image of my desired output:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMu4J.png)

I think the right answer is likely something like this:

```
gold_df.loc[gold_df['red_or_blue_side'] == 'blue', :] = \
                            BLUE_VALUES - BLUE_VALUES.shifted_down
gold_df.loc[gold_df['red_or_blue_side'] == 'red', :] = \
                            RED_VALUES - RED_VALUES.shifted_up
```

I'm not clear on two things with that code. I need to select all the columns except the first two to calculate the differences. I also don't know how to select the values and the shifted values across all the relevant columns.

Thank you for the help. Please let me know if more information is needed.

-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `groupby` `match_id` and then find the difference in each direction using `.diff` and then add the two components.

```
g = df.groupby('match_id', sort=False)[df.columns[2:]]
df = g.diff().fillna(0) + g.diff(-1).fillna(0)

df

min_0  min_1  min_2  min_3  min_4  min_5  min_6  min_7   min_8   min_9  \
0    0.0   15.0   46.0 -133.0  -60.0 -904.0 -505.0 -852.0  -763.0 -1224.0   
1    0.0  -15.0  -46.0  133.0   60.0  904.0  505.0  852.0   763.0  1224.0   
2    0.0    0.0    0.0   89.0  -92.0 -174.0  191.0   69.0   253.0   362.0   
3    0.0    0.0    0.0  -89.0   92.0  174.0 -191.0  -69.0  -253.0  -362.0   
4    0.0    0.0   17.0 -106.0 -136.0  400.0  363.0  829.0  1532.0  1862.0   
5    0.0    0.0  -17.0  106.0  136.0 -400.0 -363.0 -829.0 -1532.0 -1862.0   

    ...    min_71  min_72  min_73  min_74  min_75  min_76  min_77  min_78  \
0   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   
1   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   
2   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   
3   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   
4   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   
5   ...       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0   

   min_79  min_80  
0     0.0     0.0  
1     0.0     0.0  
2     0.0     0.0  
3     0.0     0.0  
4     0.0     0.0  
5     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Thank you all, this answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To select all columns except the first two:

```
df[df.columns[2:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all columns except the first two:

```
df.iloc[:,2:]
```